# Suppress Value Conversion warning

Tags: warnings, xcode6.3

What flag should i use to suppress Value Conversion Warning in Xcode?

These Warnings are just annoying. Don't do anything harmful in compiling or execution of program.

Answer (score 0):

-w flag against that header file solved the issue.